# Elasticseach searching partial text

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm tryng to create a index with the following mapping : 
createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(document.indexName());

```
         XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .startObject("my_type")
                        .startObject("properties")
                            .startObject("nombre")
                                .field("type", "string")
                                .field("index", "not_analyzed")
                            .endObject()                                
                            .startObject("codigo")
                                .field("type", "string")
                                .field("index", "not_analyzed")
                            .endObject()                                
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();

         createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping("my_type", mappingBuilder);
```

Then, if I try the folowing search :

```
GET /hogan/tipos-documento/_search?pretty
{ 
     "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {"wildcard": {
                  "nombre": {
                     "value": "*Type 2*"
                  }
               }}
            ] 
        }
     }
}
```

There is not problem. But if I try "value" : "*type 2* there is not result because "wildcard" is case-sensitive.

Is there any way to do searches on insensitive cases? Maybe by doing the index in another way...

Simplifying, I would like entities like :

```
public class Entity{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and having a search form where user could enter partial text of "name" (in upper or lower case" to make a search

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `nombre` field shouldn't be `index: not_analyzed` but analyzed with a `keyword` and `lowercase` analyzer. Something like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "keyword_lowercase": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
....
```

and then, in the mapping:

```
            "nombre": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase"
            }
```

Comment: I have tried do this configurationg but still is not possible to find results when I do :  "value": "*type 2*", It's working with :  "value": "*type*". Now I can search in insensitive case but not using two words( type and 2)

Comment: Are you sure the mapping has been applied correctly. After indexing the documents, check the mapping `GET /some_index/_mapping`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have checked with /hogan/_mapping and also with /hogan. With /hogan I can see the differents mappings. To create the index I have used the code in the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36745584/6161679

Comment: `analisis` is spellt wrong. It should be `analysis`.