# MapperParsingException creating elasticsearch index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create the following index and mapping.

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("my_index");



            XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .startObject("my_type")
                            .startObject("properties")
                                .startObject("nombre")
                                    .field("analyzer", "keyword_lowercase")
                                    .field("type", "string")                                    
                                .endObject()                                
                                .startObject("codigo")
                                    .field("type", "string")
                                    .field("analyzer", "keyword_lowercase")
                                .endObject()                                
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject();

             createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping(document.type(), mappingBuilder);


            XContentBuilder mappingSettingsBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()                          
                            .startObject("index")
                                .startObject("analisis")
                                    .startObject("analyzer")
                                        .startObject("keyword_lowercase")
                                            .field("type","custom")
                                            .field("tokenizer","keyword")
                                            .array("filter", "lowercase")
                                        .endObject()
                                    .endObject()
                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()                            
                    .endObject();

            createIndexRequestBuilder.setSettings(mappingSettingsBuilder);


            createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: analyzer
>   [keyword_lowercase] not found for field [codigo]

I guess I have to close/open the index in any way to get success but I don´t know when ... I have tested several things without success. Any idea?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: This should be fixed: `.startObject("analisis")` into `.startObject("analysis")`

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible to do mapping and index in separate thread when we arre using create api. The solution is do it as the same time :

```
        XContentBuilder mappingCreateBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .startObject("mappings")
                        .startObject(document.type())
                            .startObject("properties")
                                .startObject("nombre")
                                    .field("analyzer", "keyword_lowercase")
                                    .field("type", "string")                                    
                                .endObject()                                
                                .startObject("codigo")
                                    .field("type", "string")
                                    .field("analyzer", "keyword_lowercase")
                                .endObject()                                
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .startObject("settings")
                        .startObject("index")
                            .startObject("analisis")
                                .startObject("analyzer")
                                    .startObject("keyword_lowercase")
                                        .field("type","custom")
                                        .field("tokenizer","keyword")
                                        .array("filter", "lowercase")
                                    .endObject()
                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();

        createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(document.indexName());

        createIndexRequestBuilder.setSettings(mappingCreateBuilder);
        createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: As I mentioned in another post, `.startObject("analisis")` should actually be `.startObject("analysis")`.

Comment: My response was incorrect. Val was right. I shold change analisis by analysis